# Why std::map overloaded operator < does not use the Compare

Tags: c++, stl

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operators/ I noticed:

"Notice that none of these operations take into consideration the internal comparison object of either container, but compare the elements (of type value_type) directly."

this is to say that the overloaded operator "<" is not using the `Compare` in its declaration
(refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

```
std::map
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
           class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
           > class map;
```

where the `Compare` is

> Compare: A binary predicate that takes two element keys as arguments
>   and returns a `bool`. The expression `comp(a,b)`, where `comp` is an object
>   of this type and `a` and `b` are key values, shall return true if `a` is
>   considered to go before `b` in the strict weak ordering the function
>   defines. The map object uses this expression to determine both the
>   order the elements follow in the container and whether two element
>   keys are equivalent (by comparing them reflexively: they are
>   equivalent if `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a))`. No two elements in a map
>   container can have equivalent keys. This can be a function pointer or
>   a function object (see constructor for an example). This defaults to
>   `less<T>`, which returns the same as applying the less-than operator
>   `(a<b)`. Aliased as member type `map::key_compare`.

I don't quite understand it, why not just use `Compare` in the "<" operator?

Comment: Maybe the idea was that `<` should use `<`, but I would sure like to hear a less guessy response.

Comment: (in gcc), they explicitly call `lexicographical_compare`, I don't see why they don't simply propgate the compare function to this, as far as I can see, it's available... My guess would be that the `Compare` function can be arbitrarily complex, and for this case, it's only interested in whether the element at the same location is the same, so a simpler `<` could be more efficient - but it's a guess...

Comment: @Nim presumably if they propagated the `Compare` functor then the behaviour would deviate from something specified in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `std::map` overloaded `operator <` does not use the `Compare`

A very good reason is that it would not be easy to ensure behaviour that makes sense. Given that the `Compare` functor can be stateful, two maps of the same type could have completely different ordering criteria. For example,

```
struct Cmp
{
  Comp(bool flip) : flip(flip) {}

  bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const
  {
    return flip ? lhs < rhs : rhs < lhs;
  }

  bool flip;
};
```

These two maps have the same type, but different ordering:

```
std::map<int, std::string, Cmp> m0(Cmp(false));
std::map<int, std::string, Cmp> m1(Cmp(true));

bool b = m0 < m1; // which Cmp should this use?
```

This is not necessarily a reason for using `<` etc, but a good reason not to use `Compare`.

Comment: The `flip` here might be a bit rare but I agree that `<` can behave differently during string comparison, whether case sensitive or not... i think i get it.

Comment: @athos The point is that two functors of the same type can have different behaviour. This artificial example is just to illustrate that.

Answer (score 4):

`Compare` is for comparing `key_type`.  The map's `<` operator is actually comparing <s>`mapped_type`</s> `value_type`, not `key_type`, so `Compare` would not be applicable.  `value_type` is the pair of `key_type` and `mapped_type`.

To be honest, though, I think giving map an `operator<` in the first place is a case of operator overloading gone too far.  It's not immediately obvious what is means to say one map is "less than" another.  If you want `lexigraphical_compare`, I'd recommend calling it directly, or at least documenting in your code what your map comparison means.

Comment: do you mean `Compare` is comparing `key_type`, while `<` is comparing `map::mapped_type`? I don't get you...

Comment: `Compare` is used internally in order to sort the keys of a given map (used so that looking up keys can be done in O(lg n) and also allowing things like `std::lower_bound` to work). The `operator<` of the map is used to compare two maps to each other.

Comment: Typically one would expect comparisons to make sense only between objects of the same type. Two maps with different `compare` functions, seem like two different types to me. If they used the same `compare` function, it might make sense to use it as a `<` operator. But I don't know if it is possible to decide at compile time if the `compare` functions are the same.

Comment: Edited to be more explicit about key_type vs mapped_type

Comment: @ArunR Two maps of the same type can have completely different orderings. See my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: There may be duplicate keys between the two maps being compared, in which case the elements would be compared.