# std::map: overloading the operator< with a parameter other than the key's class

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, operator-keyword

*This is my first post - sorry if I mess any of the site's conventions.
Please point out any mistakes I make so i could fix them/not repeat them.*

[This post may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800181/why-stdmap-overloaded-operator-does-not-use-the-compare)

[c++ reference: std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

[c++ reference: std::map - rational operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operators/)

I want to be able to use `std::map`'s `operator[]` by putting an `std::string` between the brackets - even though the key of the `map` isn't `std::string`.

here's the code

```
class myKey
{
public:
    std::string _name;

    myKey(std::string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    bool operator<(const myKey& other) const
    {
        if (this->_name < other._name)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<myKey, int> map;
    myKey temp("keyString");
    map[temp] = 1;
    std::cout << map[temp];

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So far this works fine - but as you can see, the only thing the operator uses is the `std::string _name` field of the class.
I wan't to be able to look up a value in the map, by only entering a string like so: `map["keyString"]`.

I have tried overloading the `operator<` of `myKey`, but it didn't help.

```
bool operator<(const std::string name) const
{
    if (this->_name < name)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried adding `myKey::myKey(const char *name)`?

Answer (score 1):

`""` is a string literal, of type `const char*`. The reason why it doesn't work when you do `map["keyString"]` is because `"keyString"` first has to be converted to a `std::string`, and then it can be passed as a key.

But because it has to be converted (to `std::string`) first, this is illegal.

You can just add a constructor which takes a `const char*`:

```
myKey(const char* name) : _name{ name } {}
```

---

If you don't want to add a new constructor, you can use [`std::string_literals::operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

//Note 's' after "", this means that "keyString" is of type std::string, not const char*
map["keyString"s] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rakete - you pointed out the problem.
But there's a simpler solution:
The steps:

1. Overload the `operator<` with a method that takes the parameter you want (in this case, `std::string`. Make sure you are using the correct signature of the function *checkout my `operator<` functions*
2. When trying to get a value in the map using `operator[]` make sure you enter the right value between the brackets (this is what I did wrong, entered a `string literal` like this - `map["keyString"]` instead of entering an `std::string` like this - `map[std::string("keyString")]`